# Java literate text word parsing regexp

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Firstly I was happy with  `[A-Za-z]+` 
Now I need to parse words that end with the letter "s", but i should skip words that have 2 or more first letters in upper-case.
I try something like `[\n\\ ][A-Za-z]{0,1}[a-z]*s[ \\.\\,\\?\\!\\:]+` but the first part of it  `[\n\\ ]` for some reason doesn't see the beginning of the line.

here is the example
the text is *Denis goeS to school every day!*
but the only parsed word is *goeS*

Any Ideas?

Comment: `I need to parse words that end with the letter "x"` How does _goeS_ fit in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
\b[A-Z]?[a-z]*x\b
```

the `\b` is a word boundary, I assume that what you wanted. the `?` is the shorter form of `{0,1}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([A-Z]?[a-z]*[sS])\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Denis goeS to school every day!");
while(m.find())
{
  System.out.println( m.group(1) );
}
```

The regex matches every word that starts with anything but a whitespace or 2 upper case characters, only contains lower case characters in the middle and ends on either s or S.

In your example this would match `Denis` and `goeS`. If you want to only match upper case S change the expression to `"\\b([A-Z]?[a-z]*[S])\\b"` which woudl match `goeS` and `GoeS` but not `GOeS`, `gOeS`or `goES`.

Comment: Thank you!Such a full answer!